# How to recover progress after Disconnected Session?

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

I was making a update to my application and haven't saved in a while. Then when running my program I got the "Disconnected Session" Error and now the IDE is unresponsive.

I know that if I kill the process I will lose all my progress as this has happened before, but I don't know any other way to close it.

Is there a way to save my progress?

Comment: At my company, we regularly get Disconnected Session, and the only known solution is to kill the process. But since you press Ctrl+S twice a minute or so and use some kind of source-code version control system, there really isn't any risk of major data loss.

Comment: That's why I don't understand modern times: how can an entire IDE become unstable due to sessions, let alone network related issues? How is this even remotely (pun intended) acceptable to any user? I'd no longer touch such software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the __recovery directory as this often has the most recent version of any edit. It's not always exactly what you're after but it's usually fairly good.

I find it amusing that Notepad++ remembers everything while a Professional IDE can loose it all :)

Comment: Yep. There are so many things I would change about this IDE, which unfortunately will most likely never happen. Oh well!